# Installing Chrome Native Client SDK

Tags: python, google-nativeclient

For the last few days I have been trying ti install the Native Client SDK for chrome in Windows and/or Ubuntu.
I'm behind a corporate network, and the only internet access is through an HTTP proxy with authentication involved.
When I run "naclsdk update" in Ubuntu, it shows

"urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: For what it is worth, your question gave rise to this bug being filed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=156733,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution-
not a direct one, though.
 managed to use a program to redirect the HTTPS traffic through the HTTP proxy.
I used the program called "proxifier". Works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try to download this file:

http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-mirror/nacl/nacl_sdk/naclsdk_manifest2.json

It is the native client update summary, but in the URL I replaced the **https** with **http**.  If you view the JSON file, you will see the different pepper_xx versions available.  Use the links to download the one you want, but again replace https with http.

The naclsdk update tool is very difficult to use for those of us behind a strict firewall.  It would be nice if Google provided a direct link to the latest SDK.